# Проблема доступа к поду kubectl через Nodeport сервис из бэкенда на локалхосте

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Создал кластер minikube в нем развернуто 2 пода с приложением которое анализирует Exif изображения отправленного с бэкенда [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это приложение успешно работало в контейнере docker с бэком, однако после помещения его в архитектуру кластера, не отправляет ответ. Уточняю что бэк на локалхосте, а приложение развернуто в подах кластера minikube.

yaml файл пода приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

yaml файл настроенного сервиса NodePort для доступа извне к поду
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также запрос на бэке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал разные виды сервисов, менял порты, ничего не помогало...
Может я ошибся или что то проглядел как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Т.е. вы выпаетесь из пода сделать запрос в приложение, которое находится за пределами minikube? Я думаю в таком случае `host.docker.internal` не будет работать, но можно попробовать `host.minikube.internal`.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Неа не помогло, суть в том что до самого пода запрос не доходит, если бы доходил запрос, то была бы ошибка запроса, изза host.docker.internal. Я поменял на host.minikube.internal , но ничего не изменилось

Comment: а вы уверены что у вас адрес `http://exif/exif:32368` правильный, выглядит странно, порт не в том месте

Comment: Все ок с этим, это была невнимательность, адрес пофикшен, оказывается каждую сервис ноду нужно поднимать minikube service "имя сервиса", но при каждом перезапуске он дает разные случайные порты и не очень удобно связывать ее с бэкендом, в этом и была суть проблемы